# Split Lines inside List and retrive as variable python3/telethon

Tags: python, python-3.x, split, telegram, telethon

I need to get some data from a file .py

Inside the file we have a list like this one

```
authorized=["somenick", "someid", 45345090, "deadeye", 324234 ]
```

I want to split every item inside the list authorized like:

```
Somenick
Someid
45345090
324234
deadeye
```

But I'm also using all this information for a script which work with telethon...
basically I need to retrieve those info from that list and send it via `client_messages(chat, text)`

So I will need to define the Text too and the text should be:

```
text =''' Somenick \nSomeid \n45345090 \n324234 \ndeadeye '''
```

so my problem at the moment with the actual code are:

```
async def botadminlist(e):
ciao = open('admins.py', 'r')
for line in ciao:
    x= line.split()
    for i in x: 
        y = str(i)

        m16 = await helper.control_panel.send_message(config.chat , y)
```

But it will send 5 messages with every item.. I want only one message with all information like:

```
text =''' Somenick \nSomeid \n45345090 \n324234 \ndeadeye '''
```

so I can have a nice output into telegram chat.

With 5 times I mean like for every item in the list will send a new message like

somenick is a message
some id is another message
etc..

I want all information inside the list being into a single variable called text with \n after every item.

DO NOT try to solve using those information, are for example. but in the list I will have int and str as the example. and more the 50 items probably.

Comment: So you literally have a list in your file?

Comment: Yep.. Literaly a file .py called admins.py
and the list is called: Authorized

Comment: why you don't `import` this file and you will have it as variable `authorized` and you can do `text = "\n".join(map(str, authorized))`. And if you want to keep some data in text file then maybe you should keep it as CSV or JSON.

Comment: Yeah great answer! thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ast to turn the list representation into an actual list and `join` to do your formating.

```
import ast
file = open('test.txt','r')
lst = ast.literal_eval(file.readline().strip().split('=')[1])
print('\n'.join(list(map(str,last))))
```

output

```
somenick
someid
45345090
deadeye
324234
```

Comment: Thanks, but like i said the result at the final need to be: 

somenick
someid
45345090
deadeye
324234

With /n 
at the end of the item. 
It need to be stored into a variable text or any other name but the result i need is: 


text = ''' info \n anotherinfo \n id \n int \n anotherinfo ''' 
all taken from list of course.

Comment: replace my print with a variable.

Comment: You mistype a variable, but work fine problems solved! Thanks a lot @BuddyBod